# Finding and replacing a string in many files on linux with Python

Tags: python, linux

I am attempting to find all files (on alinux system) that are called logback.xml and replace in them one string. That works perfectly well (with the scrript below) however, when there is more than 1 file in the directory that it is working in (i.e. a directory that has both logback.xml and asdkjashdkja.xml it gives an error and in a directory that has only logback.xml it does not). Here is the Python code below:

```
def replace_loglevel(file_to_edit, source_text, replace_text):
    """ Open file and replace the source_text with the replace_text strings """
    open_file = open(file_to_edit, 'r')
    text_from_original = open_file.read()
    open_file.close()

    file_to_write = open(file_to_edit, 'w')
    file_to_write.write(text_from_original.replace(source_text, replace_text))
    print "Replacing string %s with string %s in file %s" % (source_text, replace_text, file_to_edit)

def backup_and_edit_files(dir_path, backup_dir):
    """ Backup the file and replace the source_text with replace_text """
    for item in os.listdir(dir_path): # Iterate over each dir in the dir_path
        path = os.path.join(dir_path, item) # Create full path to file
        if path not in processed_files:
            if os.path.isfile(path) and item == file_to_edit: # Match filename to be the same as in file_to_edit
                print "Matched file %s " % (file_to_edit)
                print "Backing up the current file - %s - before editing" % (item)
                backup_file(path, backup_dir)
                print "Replacing loglevel from %s to %s " % (source_text, replace_text)
                replace_loglevel(path, source_text, replace_text)
                processed_files.append(path)
                print "Processed - %s" % path
            else:
                backup_and_edit_files(path, backup_dir)
```

The error that I get when there is more files in the same directory is :

> OSError: [Errno 20] Not a directory: 'path/to/file/fgfd.xml'

When I remove this fgfd.xml from the directory the script works perfectly well and finds the logback.xml and replaced the entry in it.

Any ideas ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The structure of your script while processing a directory is :

```
if os.path.isfile(path) and item == file_to_edit: # Match filename to be the same as in file_to_edit
    ... process logback.xml
else:
    backup_and_edit_files(path, backup_dir)
```

So if the directory contains another *file*, you will call `backup_and_edit` on it, and it will break because the function will immediately call `os.listdir(path)`.

You can easily fix that with following structure :

```
if os.path.isfile(path) and item == file_to_edit: # Match filename to be the same as in file_to_edit
    ... process logback.xml
elif os.path.isdir(path): # only descend into directories
    backup_and_edit_files(path, backup_dir)
```